# Unrecognized service of Varnish 6.2.x

Tags: varnish

I have installed the image Varnish 6.2 from the Docker official images. The link is https://hub.docker.com/_/varnish

But I can't find it's service inside the container.

The output in the terminal of **service varnish restart** is

```
root@bf23572d6dad:/# service varnish restart
varnish: unrecognized service
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In our official Docker image, Varnish doesn't run as a service, it is not daemonized, but it runs in the foreground when the container is spun up.

Here's an example of running a Varnish container:

```
docker run --name varnish -d varnish:latest
```

Through the `docker top varnish` command, you can see what is running within that container:

```
➜  ~ docker top varnish
PID                 USER                TIME                COMMAND
33737               101                 0:00                varnishd -F -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl
33796               102                 0:00                {cache-main} varnishd -F -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl
```

As you can see, the main `varnishd` process is running, however the `-F` flag indicates that it is running in the foreground.

As per Docker best practices, a container should only have 1 concern and only run a single process. Using service managers to run certain processes in the background, is not advised. If a process running in the foreground fails, the container will fail and Docker can attempt to restart it.

Comment: How can we reload the varnish inside the container?
Because I want to modify the default.vcl to test

Comment: Either mount your local VCL file into `/etc/varnish/default.vcl` on your container.

Or when you're on the bash shell of your container you the following sequence of commands to reload your VCL:

`varnishadm vcl.load a /etc/varnish/default.vcl` and `varnishadm vcl.use a`

In this case the value `a` is just a label. You can use whichever label you want.